# Windows 10 ,MSMQ, PowerShell

Tags: msmq

By mistake I deleted the MSMQ user from (C:\Windows\System32\msmq\storage) permissions, now the messaging queue not visible at computer management because the bath can’t be found, how can I get back that MSMQ user I can’t find it in the local users, thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible to completely remove MSMQ from windows features.. then re-add it?  I can't think of anything else that is going to do the magic for you..  you need aspects of it's setup operation and not just to put files back.. hopefully some MSMQ expert will come along soon! :)

Comment: I already tried and found that msmq features shadow ac't remove it

Answer (score 0):

[Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system)

1. Open an elevated command prompt.
2. If you are running Windows 10, Windows 8.1 or Windows 8, first run the inbox Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) tool prior to running the System File Checker.  (If you are running Windows 7 or Windows Vista, skip to Step 3.)

   `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`
3. After DISM completes, run `sfc /scannow`

Comment: There is not a chance that is going to solve anything whatsoever.

Comment: Hopefully, I will be proven wrong.